# Wireless button

Tags: gpio, wireless

I'm looking for a wireless button solution to send signals to my raspberry pi (model B).

The setup is as following; 
I have a lifx light bulb and I'm able to control with the smartphone app and through my raspberry pi (through a local website or just commands). Problem is that I want to be able to control it with a physical button (without turning it off completely so not a normal light-switch).

So I'd like to have a wireless button that can send a signal to my raspi where I can process it.
I'm guessing I'm looking for a remote control that can connect with a GPIO receiver?
Does anybody know any good senders and/or receivers that work with a raspi?
Relatively new to this so I don't really know what to look for or what's good/bad.
A sender with multiple buttons or even a fader would be even better.

Any help is welcome.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this 434 MHz [Receiver](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10532)/[Transmitter](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10534)

You can build your remote with an Arduino clone and buttons/potentiometers/rotary encoders.